# Using Reference in c++

Tags: c++

I am using a global instance of a class like Class A; A a1; Now I am using this global variable in other functions using reference as A& a2 = a1; such that all changes done locally are reflected globally. I just wanted to check whether destructor for a2 will be called as soon its local scope ends?

Please clarify.

Comment: Whats your actually want to do ? Can you more specify ?

Comment: I wanted to change global object when ever it is referenced and used in any of the function. In my case I want to do some Cleanup of member variables of class as soon as any of the variable which references global variable goes out of scope.

Comment: @algo-geeks Then you are going to have to do that a different way. Sounds like you are fighting the language instead of working with it. Maybe a rethink is needed?

Comment: @algo-geeks You could create a **class** that contains a reference to your global. That class would have a destructor and that would be called when the local object goes out of scope. Still sounds a bit weird however. Are you trying to encode information about the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a2 is a reference so it does not have a destructor.

The destructor for a1 will only be called when the program exits. What exactly are you expecting to happen when a2's local scope ends?

Answer (score 0):

References are nothing but pointers and in fact many compilers convert references to pointers internally. As pointers don't have a destructor so does reference. Hence at the end of  function golbal object a1 will remain as it is and it's destuctor will be called only at the end of the program.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi